# Keyframe seconds doesnt fit the animation

Tags: animation

[image: Fit problem]

I have a running animation. I exported it from a very old game, but I have an issue with the animation. The markers don't fit the second. For this reason the animation is shaking little bit.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Keyframes on your timeline should be in position of seconds? BTW your current timeline doesnt display seconds but frames. To switch press Control+T. Also to have 3 keyframes per frame is quite a lot, doesnt play animation too fast? It looks like you need to scale animation when import (if its BVH) or try to scale keyframes on timeline. Probably better to post part or simplified blend with issue via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and paste link into your Question.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Mb8QpkpA" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Mb8QpkpA/)

Comment: thank you for your attention.As I said, the game is too old.Game company is bankrupt.And i have tool converts gr2 files do .dae file.i cant re scale the animation from tool that's all i can do. thanks

Comment: You are welcome, but I asked to place code (link) into your question not as Comment. Thank you for keeping thread clear for followers.

Comment: Wow nice and smooth, right shoulder not shaking anymore :)) this is perfect. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Snap keyframes to frames

Imported animation seems to be scaled down in time, three keyframes in frame is not usual. So original was probably designed for higher FPS (frame per second).

First you need to scale keyframes up, but by default blender use *Snap to* **Nearest Frame**, that cause in your case deleting (merging) all keyframes in between frames.

[image]

To avoid that, change to **No Auto-Snap**

[image]

In *Pose mode* select all bones. Go to *Dope Sheet*, select all keyframes and scale <kbd>S</kbd> them up with *Current frame* at zero, in your case scale to 3.482 seems to fit most of the keyframes on frame position. (Hard to say why they are not set precisely.)

[image]

Now you can switch *Snap to* **Nearest Frame** back and with all selected press <kbd>G</kbd> to move, but you dont really want to move, just move a bit so keyframes jump on frame positions and hit enter. Now you should have all keyframes aligned to frames.

[image]

### Run cycle duration 0.76666s

Your import in length of 19 frames fits approximately to 25 fps. If you want to scale keyframes to fit frames you would have to increase FPS (frame per second).

Scaling keyframes per frame gives 65 frames with first keyframe on frame 1 (that is common start for blender). Last keyframe generates jump in motion, so I delete them. Since you know you have like **64 frames** that should takes **0.766666s** you should change fps to (64/76.6666%*100%) **84 fps**. I dont know if there are some standards for game cycles, but I expected 60 or 120 so it is a bit weird.

[image]

[image]

---

Note:
BTW I don't have any shake even with your blend. So if you are OK to keep 24 fps with just 19 frames that with merged all keyframes in between - just select all bones in pose mode and press G to move a bit with mouse over Dope Sheet and release, keyframes jumps to frame position.

[image]